# How to add a dependency to react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm trying to add the following library to a react project:

```
https://github.com/rndme/download
```

I've done the following:

```
yarn add https://github.com/rndme/download
```

and got this response:

```
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ downloadjs@1.4.8
info All dependencies
└─ downloadjs@1.4.8
✨  Done in 2.19s.
```

Then I updated the package.json to include it:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-cookie": "3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "6.5.0",
    "downloadjs": "1.4.8"
  },
```

And added some code to call it:

```
  async downloadFile(file, url) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const blob = res.blob();

    // from downloadjs it will download your file
    download(blob, file, "text/plain");  
  }
```

However, it doesn't compile:

```
Failed to compile
./src/LicenseList.js
  Line 64:  'download' is not defined  no-undef
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Why do you have to update `package.json` yourself?

Comment: Just `npm install downloadjs` in your rooter folder, and you are good to go!

Comment: ...or if you can't, and need to install from github directly, it might help to tell us *why*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `yarn add <dependency>`, your desired dependency is actually added to the `package.json` and then being downloaded into the `node_modules` folder. You don't have to update the `package.json` manually in this case. Did you execute `yarn add` in the root folder of your project? This is essential. The lack of a lockfile indicates, that you are executing `yarn install` or `yarn add` the first time in this folder. A lockfile is usually added to the Git repository, so it seems, that you are running that command at the wrong path.

Regarding the compilation error: After running `yarn add`, you need to import the desired function/module in your code. Then, you can use the functionality. It seems that you did not import the module correctly. You need to add a statement `import downloadjs from 'downloadjs'` on top of your JavaScript file.

So, these are the steps you need to follow when adding a new dependency:

1. Go to the project root and run `yarn add <dependency>`, in this case `yarn add downloadjs`. You usually find the exact name of the dependency in the project's package.json file in the Git repository. You could check, if there is now a folder `./node_modules/downloadjs` with the desired content and a reference to that package in the `package.json` and the lockfile.
2. Depending on your module bundler, you need to import the now installed dependency. With require.js, you would add a statement like this:

   ```
   const downloadjs = require('downloadjs');
   ```

   Usually, you would however import it like this:

   ```
   import downloadjs from 'downloadjs';
   ```
3. Then, you have the imported module saved in the variable `downloadjs`. You can then use the module like described in the documentation. In this case, it would be:

   ```
   downloadjs(data, strFileName, strMimeType);
   ```

Comment: great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using yarn you just need to write `yarn add mydepencyname` or `yarn add -D mydependencyname` to add a devDependency (that is to say "only useful during the development phase".

You will find the correct dependency name on npm.com. To update your dependencies, just type `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`, and press on the spacebar to select the package you want to update.

Answer (score 1):

I visited the Repo for this package and it says the below:

> Simple global download function via `<script>` include
>   download(data, strFileName, strMimeType);

So you need to include a script tag and reference the path under node_modules to this package to use this. Something along the lines of 
`<script src="/node_modules/downloadjs" />`
Then the global download function will be available to your code...Let me know if it makes sense...
There is another method described in the Repo
`require("downloadjs")(data, strFileName, strMimeType);`

Comment: Usually, you do not want to combine a module bundler and global `<script>` imports.

Comment: Understood and appreciated but the authors of this Repo seem to have this package as  an AMD module ...

Comment: This does not pose a problem. You could import the `downloadjs` module with a regular `import` statement. I just checked.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 could you give me the import statement that worked for you? I'm still having trouble with it.

Comment: This one works: `import downloadjs from 'downloadjs';`